# Custom Theme Want To Remove One Category From All Displays

Tags: posts, categories, wp-admin, admin-menu, customization

I created my own custom Wordpress theme for my website, everything is great. However, I have a strange need, I have one category which is kind of a 'placeholder' for content which is automated and used by an automated background process. Each time this process finds new content to put into that category I end up with another entry when I go to the admin screen to post or edit any of the posts which I manually enter. Since it is more than just myself, I really want a way to just completely hide that one category from being shown in the Admin 'Edit/Post' screen to keep it nice and lean.

I've poked around in some of the source code files, however, I have come to the point of frustration. Been searching around on Google and other places for any idea, yet, keep coming up empty.

Does anyone know how to do this, or even IF it can be done?

Thanks,

Derek

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could imagine is *removing, rewriting, replacing* the meta box.

```
// First remove the original one
function wpse21483_remove_catbox()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'post_categories_meta_box', 'post', 'side' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse21483_remove_catbox' ); // not sure about the hook

function wpse21483_new_catbox()
{
    // re-define - take a look at /wp-admin/include/metaboxes.php
}
// Hook the new one
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse21483_new_catbox' );
```

---

**Edit:** Maybe you can use a the *filter* for the categories dropdown

```
function wpse21483_alter_catbox( $output )
{
    global $current_screen;
    $id = $current_screen->id;
    // abort if not on post screen
    if ( $id !== 'post' )
        return;

    // search/replace the category
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'wpse21483_alter_catbox', 10, 1 )
```

Comment: I assume, to use that, I would place it in my functions file?

Comment: Yes, functions.php is a good place for custom hacks. But you still have to define the search/replace. See the line where I commented that. For a start, replace the comment line with `echo '<pre>'; print_r($output); echo '</pre>';` to see how `$output` is currently built.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a plugin called Ultimate Category Excluder 
Easily exclude categories from your front page, feeds, search , and archives

http://www.planetmike.com/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/

it worked for me :)

Hope this is an easy fix